# Debug source files from a nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have include my source code in an internal nuget package. So that the top level inside the package looks like this

```
lib
src
name.of.package.XXXX.nupkg
```

How can I inform VS2013 the location of the source code so that I can step into it? (Without having to manually point to the src location)

Thanks

Comment: Ever Find a solution